# Allow permission for get method for all users and allow post method for super user only in django rest api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ViewSet for the Category class"""

    queryset = models.Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

How do I allow get method for all user and post method for superusers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the request on your function for whether it is a `POST` or a `GET`. If it's a post, you can check the credentials of the user to verify if they are a superuser.

```
def list(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            # let superuser do their thing
        else:
            # error! you're not allowed to do this!
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        # you're any user who is allowed to do their thing
```